# Наследование и создание объекта

Tags: c++, ооп

Здравствуйте! Такая ситуация. Программа для подсчета зарплат сотрудникам.

Сотрудников 3 вида.

Есть базовый класс **worker**, от него получается 3 наследника: **employee**, **manager**, **sales**. Сведения о сотрудниках хранятся в базе данных.

Вот вытаскиваем мы сведения о каком-то сотруднике, в графе род деятельности - **employee**. Как создать объект именно класса **employee**? Т.е. для **manager** - объект класса **manager** и т.д.

Comment: А в чём видится сложность?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <functional>

class Worker
{
public:
    virtual std::string name() = 0;
};

class Manager : public Worker
{
public:
    virtual std::string name() override
    {
        return "I am Manager";
    }
};

class Employee : public Worker
{
public:
    virtual std::string name() override
    {
        return "I am Employee";
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::map<std::string, std::function<Worker*()>> workerFactory;
    workerFactory["manager"] = []{return new Manager();};
    workerFactory["employee"] = []{return new Employee();};

    Worker *worker1 = workerFactory["manager"]();
    Worker *worker2 = workerFactory["employee"]();

    std::cout << worker1->name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << worker2->name() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
I am Manager
I am Employee
```